# Knockout click event in Appframework header not triggering

Tags: javascript, cordova, knockout.js, appframework

I am making a Cordova/Phonegap app using Appframework and Knockout js for front and back end. The issue I am running into is occurring in the header of the firstly loaded panel.

The HTML:

```
<div id="afui">
    <div id="content">
        <!--CLASS LIST VIEW -->
        <div class="panel" title="Classes" id="classList" 
             data-footer="none" selected="true">
            <header>
                <div style="float:right" data-bind="click:addClass" 
                     class="button icon add white"></div>
                <h1>Classes</h1>
            </header>
            <ul class="list" data-bind="foreach: classes">
                <li data-bind="click:openClass, attr: { id: id, name: name }">
                    <a href="#categoryList">
                      <span style="padding-right:20px" data-bind="text: name">
                      </span>Grade:
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- CATEGORY VIEW -->
        <div class="panel" id="categoryList" title="Class Name">
            <header>
                <a id="backButton" href="javascript:;" class="button" 
                   style="visibility: visible; ">Back</a>
                <h1 data-bind="text: header "></h1>
                 <div style="float:right" data-bind="click:addCategory" 
                      class="button icon add white">
                 </div>
            </header>
            <ul class="list" data-bind="foreach: categories">
                <li data-bind="text:name"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So in the first panel of `id="classList"` the `addClass` button in the header does not get triggered when clicked, tapped, or any other sort of user interaction.
If I tap on a list item with a link to the panel of `id="categoryList"` and transition to that panel, the button in the top right of that header with event `click:addCategory` *DOES* work.

The only way I can get the `addClass` click event to fire is when I init my models...

```
ko.applyBindings(classModel, document.getElementById('classList'));
ko.applyBindings(categoryModel, document.getElementById('categoryList'));
```

is by not specifying the second parameter for the `classModel` ko binding. Of course this will be a problem, because I have multiple views and need to specify which container each of my models should observe.

VIEW MODELS

ClassModel:

```
function classInfo(name, id, parent) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(name);
    self.score = ko.observable('');
    self.id = ko.observable(id);

    self.openClass = function(data, event) {
        parent.currentClass(event.currentTarget.name);
    };
}

function classListViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    //class array object
    self.classes = ko.observableArray([]);

    //current class name
    self.currentClass = ko.observable().publishOn("currentClass");

    //remove a class from the model
    self.removeClass = function(obj) {
      //remove the class
    };

    //add a new class to the model
    self.addClass = function() {
        //add a new using classInfo object
    };
}
```

So, what is going on here? Is Appframework doing something weird to the header on the main page causing the `click:addClass` event to not fire?

Any insight/help would be much appreciate, thanks!

Comment: you need to post your view model

Comment: Is your id `classList` unique?

Comment: addClass function may not be in your parent viewmodel or post viewmodel so we can find out the problem

Comment: I added my classListViewModel..let me know what you guys think